# Live Video Facebook API with FFMPEG nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ffmpeg

I have created Object Live Video as Facebook's document.

`"stream_url": "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/641310872699778?ds=1&a=AaYx3JYoFLTXAvBK`"

I using https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg for stream but I failed.

Does anyone have solutions to stream video file (eg: mp4) to Object Video Facebook API?

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg'),
  fs = require('fs');

  // open input stream
var infs = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/2.mp4');

infs.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
var publish = "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/641310872699778?ds=1&a=AaYx3JYoFLTXAvBK";
// make sure you set the correct path to your video file
var proc = ffmpeg(infs)

  .format('mp4')
  .size('320x?')
  .videoBitrate('512k')
  .videoCodec('libx264')
  .fps(24)
  .audioBitrate('96k')
  .audioCodec('aac')
  .audioFrequency(22050)
  .audioChannels(2)
  // setup event handlers
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
  })
  // save to stream
  .save(publish); //end = true, close output stream after writing
```

**`an error happened: ffmpeg exited with code 1: rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/641310872699778?ds=1&a=AaYx3JYoFLTXAvBK: Operation not permitted`**

Comment: Same problem, but using just raw ffmpeg, did you find a solution in the meanwhile. Using Facebook OpenGraph API I was able to see that it's a problem with the authentication

Comment: try using single quotes ' in var publish with inside all the rtmp url, http://stream-recorder.com/forum/ffmpeg-live-facebook-t21044.html?s=303eefb03fa1a7be191863303d585acd&amp;

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too when I tried to send an mp4 to a rtmp server. Convert the file to flv first because that is the file type that rtmp servers read and decode.

```
ffmpeg(infs).videoCodec('libx264').audioCodec('aac').toFormat('flv').save(publish)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried passing a quoted input? Something like this:

```
publish = "\"rtmp://... live=1 app=...\"";
```